# Select next() with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, traversal

I have a `div.expander` which is the button to show/hide all the table rows (tr) in the next (following) table.

The problem I am having is selecting the table row to open and close. My code opens and closed all the tr's on the page (there are 3 tables) with the class slide, but I only want to close all  in the *next* table from the clicked div. I tried a few things like

```
 $(this).find('tr.slider').toggleClass('hidden');
 $(this).next('tr.slider').toggleClass('hidden');

$('.expander').click(function() {
  $('tr.slider').toggleClass('hidden');
  $(this).toggleClass('closed');
  if ($(this).attr('class').split(' ').slice(-1) == 'closed') {
     $(this).html('Hide Details');
     }
  else {
    $(this).html('View Details');
  }
});
```

Below is my HTML structure;

```
<div class="edit-basket">
<a href ="#"><img src="/images/edit16_ico.png" width="16" height="18" alt="edit icon" /><p>Edit</p></a>
</div>
<div class = "tbl-title">
<h3>Journey 2</h3>
</div>


<table id="journey1"  cellspacing ="0" class="tbl basket">
<tbody>
<tr class="odd">
    <td  colspan="3"> <h3>Origin - Destination</h3></td><td colspan="2" class="top-right-corner"><div class="expander">View Details</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="odd slider">
```

Comment: I'd go with a .each(function () { ... })

Answer (score 0):

#### Description

If you want to hide all rows, you can hide the whole "next" table.

#### Sample

```
$('.expander').click(function() {
  var nextTable = $(this).next();
  nextTable.toggleClass('hidden');

  if (nextTable.attr("class") == "") {
     $(this).html('Hide Details');
  }
  else {
    $(this).html('View Details');
  }
});
```

#### More Information

#### [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/emZeX/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your HTML looks like:

```
<div class="expander">...</div>
<table>...</table>

<div class="expander">...</div>
<table>...</table>

<div class="expander">...</div>
<table>...</table>
```

If so, you are probably working too hard.  You could simply hide the table.

```
$(this).next().hide(); // or show() depending on the state of your expander
```

Or if you really want to use your classes and hide the rows.

```
$(this).next().find('tr.slider').toggleClass('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.expander').click(function() {
   $(this).next('table').find('tr.slider').toggleClass('hidden');
   ...
```

given your DOM structure looks like:

```
<div class="expander">-</div>
<table>
    <tr>
    ...
```